# Why the value of split is false in the test set?

Tags: r, machine-learning

can someone explain to me why the value of split is false in the test set?

```
split = sample.split(dataset$Salary, SplitRatio = 2/3)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)
```

Comment: No, we can't, not unless you provide a lot more information about your data. Please include a reproducible example.

Comment: Do you mean "why the value of `split` is `FALSE` *in `test_set`*" or "why the value of `split` is `FALSE` *in the call to `subset` that creates `test_set`*"?

Comment: in the call to subset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you got this code from some kind of `caTools` documentation? I recommend trying to run the first line of code and it should start to make sense.

Basically what `caTools::sample.split` does is create a random vector of length `nrow(x)` with TRUEs and FALSEs, in the given ratio. Let's take the `iris` dataset for example (which has 150 rows):

```
split = sample.split(iris$Sepal.Length, SplitRatio = 2/3)
```

The result will be a 150 item vector with 2/3 TRUE and 1/3 FALSE.

Next you use the `subset` function to extract all the rows `i` from `iris` where `split[i] == TRUE` to create the training set and use all the rows `i` from `iris` where `split[i] == FALSE` to create the test set.

That is why you use `split == TRUE` in the training set and `split == FALSE` in the test set

Comment: it was from a course im taking, thank you that cleared things for me